# SwiftEmitModule normal x86_64 Release Build Failure in React Native

Tags: ios, swift, react-native

```
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
        SwiftEmitModule normal x86_64 Emitting\ module\ for\ FieldRocket (in target 'FieldRocket' from project 'FieldRocket')
        SwiftCompile normal x86_64 Compiling\ ExpoModulesProvider.swift /Users/kodyk/SoftEngineering/ServiceRocketMobile/ios/Pods/Target\ Support\ Files/Pods-FieldRocket/ExpoModulesProvider.swift (in target 'FieldRocket' from project 'FieldRocket')
        SwiftCompile normal x86_64 /Users/kodyk/SoftEngineering/ServiceRocketMobile/ios/Pods/Target\ Support\ Files/Pods-FieldRocket/ExpoModulesProvider.swift (in target 'FieldRocket' from project 'FieldRocket')
        SwiftCompile normal x86_64 Compiling\ noop-file.swift /Users/kodyk/SoftEngineering/ServiceRocketMobile/ios/FieldRocket/noop-file.swift (in target 'FieldRocket' from project 'FieldRocket')
        SwiftCompile normal x86_64 /Users/kodyk/SoftEngineering/ServiceRocketMobile/ios/FieldRocket/noop-file.swift (in target 'FieldRocket' from project 'FieldRocket')
(5 failures)
]
```

This error doesn't happen when I run: `react-native run-ios`, but does happen when I run it in release mode `react-native run-ios --configuration Release`.

Answer (score 0):

This was occuring because during the process of upgrading my React Native version from 0.64.3 to 0.72.3, I was forced to increase the target iOS to `13` rather than it's previous version of `12.4`. This solved a bunch of build issues with my node dependencies that my app relies on. However, I accidentally only increased the version in my debug mode.

I went to XCode -> Targets -> My App -> Build Settings -> Deployment -> iOS Deployment Target.

My Debug mode was set to 13, but my Release mode was still 12.4. After setting my release target to iOS 13, I was able to fix this build error.

[image]